# Can a RDS Multi AZ w/one standby be converted to Multi AZ w/two readable standbys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm looking at the two AWS RDS options for highly available databases :

- Multi-AZ with one standby
- Multi-AZ with two readable standbys

> https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/

My understanding is that with **Multi-AZ with one standby**, you pay for two instances. However, you can only use one instance. When a failure occurs, the other instance takes over.

With the **Multi-AZ with two readable standbys** option, am I right that we are then talking about a total of 3 instances? A writer instance, and two reader instances (and not a writer + failover writer + two readers)?

If I start out with **Multi-AZ with one standby**, can this setup be converted to a **Multi-AZ with two readable standbys** if I down the road find out that I'd like to have a reader?

I could probably add a reader node to the **Multi-AZ with one standby**, but then I'd miss out on the faster failover time and lower commit latency which comes with the **Multi-AZ with two readable standbys**.

Comment: Interesting question. The two standby option is very new so not many people will have experience with it. If someone here can't help I might ask AWS Support - though sometimes in AWS it's easiest just to have a play in the console. If there's no direct support you may have to snapshot / recreate your database.